# Normalization of blur of the image using Laplacian

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, laplacianofgaussian

I have an image and I am interested in computing the blurr present in the image; for that I have used openCV in build functionality called `cv2.Laplacian(image)`. But I could able to quantify the amount of blur present in the image. Is there anyway that we can compute a normalized value of the blur for a given image.

```
def blur(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fm = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
    return fm
```

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587428/how-to-detect-blur-rate-of-a-face-effectively-in-c/60593957#60593957

Comment: But I wanted to express the threshold which lies between 0 to 1; meaning the blur value should also be between 0 to 1

Comment: Take two images, with minimal and maximal blur, and use the values for a linear transformation.

Comment: There is no way to obtain a blurriness value in a general setting. You need to make assumptions about the subject in the picture and about the contrast.